# Google tag manager resetting events list on page load

Tags: google-tag-manager

We put the GTM code snippet in the site.

However the sequence of events resets every time I switch from one page to another.

For example - if a user comes on the login page, enters the login details and clicks the login button to go to the home page,  the list of events reset and I lose all data about previous events.

How can i ensure that I dont lose the event data from previous pages?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can do about the browser resetting window-level variables, that's just how they work.

You might want to reconsider the way you think about GTM and the `dataLayer`.  Instead of thinking of the `dataLayer` as a list of all past events, think of it as just a way to send data to Google Analytics (or whatever too you're using).  Google Analytics is what stores the events, the `dataLayer` is just an interface for sending them there.

Having said that, here are some potential solutions for remembering values across pages:

You could try using something like [window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), which will allow the browser to remember certain values across pages.  This isn't a solution for remembering the entire `dataLayer`, but if you have one or two bits of data you want on multiple pages, this might work.

Alternatively, if you have data that's stored on the server (like the user's ID) that you want to have client-side, you could have your server generate some code to push that data when the page loads, like this:

```js
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
  'userId': '123'
});
```

---

Edit: I just learned that [Simo Ahava found a way to do this](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/persist-datalayer-across-pages/). It is very complicated and I still recommend changing the way you think about the `dataLayer`, but it is possible.